# Ajuda para povoar um array com objetos usando um while

Tags: php, array

Eu quero ler linhas de um SQL e usá-las para criar objetos e por fim, colocar estes objetos em um array. Mas no final os meus métodos (da classe Object) não imprimem o nome do objeto.
O código para ler apenas uma linha funciona, então o **meu problema certamente está no array**.

```
<?php
    require_once 'Object.php';
    require("connect.inc");
    connect_db() or die ("Error.");
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM object") or die ("Error");

    $count = 0;
    $c[] = array();
    while ($line=mysql_fetch_array($result) && $count < 6) {
        $count ++;
        $c[$count] = new Object($line);
    }

    print ($c[1]->getName()); // Example

?>
```

Comment: Olá Bernardo, podes traduzir a pergunta para Português?

Comment: $count deveria ser $cont ou vice-versa. E tire os colchetes da declaração de $c.

Comment: desculpe, na verdade isso foi um erro de transcrição, ambos estão iguais

Comment: O erro está no if. Está `$cont < 6`, quando, acredito eu, deveria estar `$count < 6`

Comment: desculpe, como eu traduzi o código pra postar, acabei errando esta variável na hora da transcrição, mas todos os "count" estão iguais no código

Comment: Qual a utilidade desse contador? Quando não tiver mais linhas, o laço será finalizado, não há necessidade de contador.

Comment: Não estou familiarizado com o PHP, pensei que precisasse de um como no Java. Alias, isso dentro do vetor, mas ele é utilizado pq eu quero apenas as primeiras 6 linhas da tabela.

Comment: O que é essa classe Object? Você que a criou?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a intenção é armazenar as linhas em forma de um objeto no array e exibir posteriormente, poderia ser feito assim:

```
<?php
    require_once 'Object.php';
    require("connect.inc");
    connect_db() or die ("Error.");
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM object") or die ("Error");


    $c[] = array();

    while ($line=mysql_fetch_object($result) ) {
        $c[] = $line;
    }


    foreach($c as $line){
        echo $line->coluna1;//altere pelo nome das colunas da sua tabela
    }

?>
```

Sugiro fortemente que remova as funções `mysql`, pois [**seu desenvolvimento foi descontinuado**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql). Substitua por funções [`mysqli`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) ou [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).

Comment: A intenção é criar objetos com essas linhas e guardar eles no array. O construtor do Object usa o vetor "$line" para criar o objeto.

Comment: @BernardoAraujo o php já faz isso, teste este código que postei para ver. To vendo que você ta vindo do java, o php é mais flexivel em muitas coisas.

Comment: Mas onde os objetos estão sendo criados? não encontrei a chamada para o construtor.

Comment: @BernardoAraujo você testou o código? A função `mysql_fetch_object` transforma em objetos as linhas resgadas da tabela, onde as propriedades são as colunas da tabela.

Comment: É que já tenho uma classe específica com métodos que quero usar para criar estes objetos.

Comment: @BernardoAraujo então seria interessante você editar a pergunta e mostrar a estrutura da tabela do select, e adicionar também essa classe para que seja possivel testar.

Comment: Obrigado por toda a ajuda, utilizei esta resposta como base para fazer uma solução que me serviu.